# Getting structs used in dll

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Is it possible to filter all the structs declared variables used in a dll?

For static fields I'm using the following code:

```
foreach (FieldInfo targetfield in InputType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static))
{
}
```

Is there any possible way to do as such?

Answer (score 3):

You probably only want types that are:

- Value types (all structs are value types): see the [IsValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) property.
- Not enums (enums are value types, but you probably don't want to think of them as structs): see the [IsEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx) property.
- Not primitive types (e.g. `Int32`, which is a value type but, again, probably isn't something you want to consider a "struct"): see the [IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) property.

Something like this:

```
const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
var structFields = from field in InputType.GetFields(bindingFlags)
                   let type = field.FieldType
                   where type.IsValueType
                       && !type.IsEnum
                       && !type.IsPrimitive
                   select field;
foreach (var targetField in structFields) { ... }
```

One thing that might be unexpected: this will include built-in-but-non-primitive value types like [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... because they *are* structs. You'll have to decide whether that's OK or not, depending on what you're trying to do. (In my case, I didn't want them.) If you decide you don't want these in your results, a couple of possibilities might be:

- Filter them out explicitly (`type != typeof(DateTime)`).
- Filter out everything from the mscorlib assembly (`type.Assembly != typeof(object).Assembly`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean member variables aka fields or local variables? In the later case, you should walk the output of a decompiler... like Cecil: http://mono-project.com/Cecil

Comment: I think the point here is to find all members of all types and all variables in functions which are structs.  Not all types declared in an assembly that are structs.